# KnockoutJS: components binding, working with objects as data type

Tags: components, mediator, knockout-3.0

I'm new to Knockout JS and I find this library very powerful, but quite hard to understand sometimes. The documentation is hudge, but it's always (too) small code snippets, so it's difficult to have the big picture, unless your coding style & philosophy paradigm are the same as KO developers.

I come from angular world, and I'm used to have an array where each item is an object with properties (id, name, etc). When I click a button, I "send" this object to a new component that will render it in a form.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I don't understand how to make things work, even with plugins like ko.mapping and ko.postbox.

Does anyone can help me to find the solution? In the working code above, I've posted my 3 very specific questions in the javascript area.

**EDIT: I answered to them, but I don't know if it's a best practice or not**.

```js
var
    // User class to give to each property the observable capacity
    User = function (rawData) {
        var self = this,
            data = rawData || {};

        self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
        self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    },

    // List component. initially in a separate file
    // (small modifs so all can be in the same file for this demo)
    cmplist = {
        viewModel: function () {
            var self = this;
            self.users = ko.observableArray([
                new User({id: 1, name: 'John'}),
                new User({id: 2, name: 'Jack'}),
                new User({id: 3, name: 'Smith'})
            ]);

            // #ANSWER 1: initialize postbox event
            self.user = ko.observable(new User()).publishOn('userEdit');

            self.showEdit = function (user) {
                // #QUESTION 1: how do I send this object to the
                //              users-form component. ko.postbox?
                // #ANSWER 1: change the observable
                self.user(user);
                console.log('show', user);
            };
        },
        template: ''
            + '<ul data-bind="foreach: users">'
            + '<li>'
            + '<button data-bind="click: $parent.showEdit">Edit</button>'
            + '&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: name"></span>'
            + '</li>'
            + '</ul>'
    },

    // Form component, initially in a separate file
    // (small modifs so all can be in the same file for this demo)
    cmpform = {
        viewModel: function () {
            var self = this;
            // #QUESTION 2: how do I recept the object sent by the
            //              list?
            // #ANSWER 2: make the observable subscribe to event
            self.user = ko.observable(new User()).subscribeTo('userEdit');

            self.save = function () {
                // #QUESTION 3: how do I notify the users-list cmp
                //              that object has changed? ko.postbox?
                window.alert('save ' + ko.toJSON(self.user()));
                console.log('save');
            };
        },
        // #ANSWER 2: call user() with parenthesis to access properties
        template: ''
            + '<form>'
            + '<p>Edit user <span data-bind="text: user().name"></span> '
            + 'with id <span data-bind="text: user().id"></span></p>'
            + '<input data-bind="textInput: user().name" />'
            + '<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>'
            + '</form>'
    };

// KO bootstrap, initially in a 3rd file
// (small modifs so all can be in the same file for this demo)
ko.components.register('users-list', cmplist);
ko.components.register('users-form', cmpform);
ko.applyBindings({});
```

```css
ul { 
  border: 1px solid blue; 
  list-style: none; 
  float: left;
}

li { 
  border: 1px solid green; 
}

form { 
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ul, li, form { 
  padding: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-postbox/0.5.2/knockout-postbox.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <users-list></users-list>
      
        <users-form></users-form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answer on question 3: At least you can notify other components of changes in an observable by using the subscribe function. (Use it like this: `myObservable.subscribe(function(data) { console.log(data); });`)

Comment: Also it looks like there's pretty decent documentation on postbox: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox :) (I don't have experience using postbox)

Comment: I took a deeper look at postbox and I came to something, but I have no idea if it's ok with this approach or not :P I added my answers in my initial post

Comment: If it works it's allright I guess ;) Also, doesn't postbox have a two way binding which means the variable is updated automatically? Or you can create another notification for pushing back the value or you can create a global data store or whatever. There are only soo many possibilities :)